# Searching a string using grep with if statement

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to find a specific string from a file using grep with IF stmt. But I am not able to do so. The input file (filename: input_file_txt) carries a whole lot of string from which I am cutting down and taking only the values that are required to be searched on. I am doing using awk and writing it to file. Then, using grep, the string is searched. I end up with strange error which I am not able to figure it out. Giving the input file content, code I used and the error message I am getting

Content of **input_file_txt**:

```
123456 ----- abcd|abcd_vasa|nodatapts|1 ----- Assigned ----- @assignee ----- 0 ----- 2015-06-12
789011 ----- abcd|efgh_vasa|yesdata|56 ----- WIP ----- @assignee ----- 0 ----- 2015-06-12
```

And my code:

```
while

read LINE
echo "$LINE"
echo "going into the loop"

do

echo $LINE|awk -F\----- '{ print $2 }' >> /var/tmp/dummy_file
cat /var/tmp/dummy_file

if [ grep -q -i -E "abcd" /var/tmp/dummy_file ];then 

count=expr "$count" + 1
echo "$count"
echo "$LINE" >> /var/tmp/dummy_ticket_NA
cat /var/tmp/dummy_ticket_NA

fi

done < /var/tmp/input_file_txt`
```

Error message I am getting is:

```
123456 ----- abcd|abcd_vasa|nodatapts|1 ----- Assigned ----- @assignee ----- 0 ----- 2015-06-12
going into the loop
abcd_vasa

going into the loop

going into the loop

going into the loop

going into the loop

going into the loop
```

Expected O/P is:

```
123456 ----- abcd|abcd_vasa|nodatapts|1 ----- Assigned ----- @assignee ----- 0 ----- 2015-06-12
going into the loop
abcd_vasa
1
abcd_vasa
```

Comment: Please see [Bash Pitfall #9](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5Bgrep_foo_myfile.5D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kojiro's link points to your issue, '[' is a command (the test command), not part of the syntax of an if statement.

The if statement you've written:

```
if [ grep -q "abcd" /var/tmp/dummy_file ];then
```

is equivalent to:

```
if test grep -q "abcd" /var/tmp/dummy_file ]; then
```

To use commands like grep in if statements just elide the brackets:

```
if grep -q "abcd" /var/tmp/dummy_file; then
    ...
fi
```

Setting `-x`, `-e` and `-u` in your bash scripts, especially `-x` when you're debugging them can be very valuable as it will print every statement that is executed in your script.  '-e' will cause your script to exit on the first unsuccessful command (fail fast) and '-u' will case any use of an undeclared variable to be an error.

Comment: Thanks for the additional note. However, is there any samples that showcases `-x`, `-e` and `-u`? just to go through them for better understanding.. ?

Comment: The above correction has worked.. I am able to see the o/p but the iteration still goes... New o/p I am getting is:                                            `123456 ----- abcd|abcd_vasa|nodatapts|1 ----- Assigned ----- @assignee ----- 0 ----- 2015-06-12
going into the loop
abcd_vasa
1
abcd_vasa                                                                                                                                                                                                               going into the loop

going into the loop

going into the loop

going into the loop`

Comment: Also I have added commands `-i`, `-E` to the existing `grep` command. Edited the original post....

Comment: Are you saying your while loop continues?  That's true - it's going to continue as long as the 'echo' succeeds (which is always).  You probably need to move the 2 echo's after the read to after the 'do' so the result of the read will be what terminates the loop.